# WordPress Loop if/else

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I am trying to create a loop for a custom post type that first calculates how many posts it contains. If it only contains one post, it should simply display the content area of the post. If the post contains more than 1 post it should display the excerpts of all the posts in the loop. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 3):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties

`found_posts` is the total number of posts returned by the query.

example code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'your_custom' );
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
   $number_of_posts = $custom_query->found_posts; 

   while( $custom_query->have_posts() ) { 
      $custom_query->the_post();

      if( $number_of_posts == 1 ) { 
         the_content(); 
      } else { 
         the_excerpt(); 
      }

   } 

   wp_reset_postdata();

}
?>
```

Comment: @nick as per your requirements, the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code & let me know the result (I've not tested)

```
<?php
$post_query = new WP_Query('post_type=post'); // replace the post type with your post type key
$total_posts_found = $post_query->found_posts;

if($total_posts_found < 2 && $total_posts_found > 0){
    if($post_query->have_posts()) : while($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();
        echo '<h1>'get_the_title().'</h1>';
        echo get_the_content();
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    if($post_query->have_posts()) : while($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();
        echo '<h1>'get_the_title().'</h1>';
        echo get_the_excerpt();
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```